# Wildfly 25: Started getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/security/RunAs

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

After upgrading to Wildfly 25 from 24, I started getting the following error:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /oc/api/authentication/token: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/security/RunAs
```

Here is the sample code on the usage of org.jboss.security.RunAs

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
if (getRoles() != null) {
    set.addAll(getRoles());
    RunAsIdentity runAs = new RunAsIdentity(getRoles().isEmpty() ? "anonymous" : getRoles().get(0), getUser(),
        set);
    SecurityContextAssociation.pushRunAsIdentity((org.jboss.security.RunAs) runAs);
}
```

This code sets the authentication and authorization on the API layer and propagates the security context to the EJB layer.

I added

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
```

to the standalone.xml file but no relief.

I tried several articles through google search but not able to see a good documentation to solve this error or migration fix.

Any documentation or pointers to resolve this error with a replacement sample source will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the release notes https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/10/05/WildFly25-Final-Released/. The legacy security has been removed in WildFly 25. You should probably be using the `javax.annotation.security.RunAs` annotation.

Comment: Hi James, I tried `code`javax.annotation.security.RunAs`code`. Here, we are setting a hard coded substitute value. I am trying to run dynamically a new user with a list of roles queried from a database. This is like running a customized service account through SSO (virtual user without exposing the real identity). Any suggestion with running a dynamic user and list of roles will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it, but maybe have a look at https://docs.wildfly.org/25/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html.